# how to trim all the spaces if there is any at the end of my string?

Tags: php, regex

my code is like this:

```
   case 'phone_number':
                        $pattern = "/^\s*\+?\s*([0-9]+\s*)+\s*(\((\+?[0-9]+\s*)+\))?\s*[0-9-\s]*[0-9]\s*(x\s*[\d]{1,})?$/";
                        //$trimmed = str_replace(' ', '', $pattern);
                        $pattern = preg_replace(' ', '', $pattern);

                break;

                default:
                        return false;
                break;

        }
        return preg_match($pattern, $data) ? true : false;
```

it's a validation for a phone number and i want if there's any spaces after the number to be removed so it won't fail with my condition of error `trim(strlen($_POST['phone_number'])) > 30`

how can i do this ? thanks a lot!

Comment: What's the problem? `trim()` does the job, but you have to use it on the string, non on its length.

Comment: You need to `trim` before you `strlen`.

Comment: Print out `$_POST` values out, and you will see what's wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are calling:

```
trim(strlen($_POST['phone_number'])) > 30
```

Which translates in:

```
strlen($_POST['number'])) --> will be 10, or 12

trim( the_number_above ) --> nothing to trim
```

And that number will be less than 30 of course - call functions in right order:

```
strlen(
    trim( $_POST['phone_numer'] )
) > 30
```

Anyway, I would trim all the input at the very beginning of the script, and not in every single check you do.